# CSS style doesn't work on PrimeNG components

Tags: html, css, angular, import, primeng

I need help with my Angular project.

I'm using the PrimeNG library, but when I use its components, inline CSS classes on the elements do not work. Could someone please help me?

- [CSS import globally in the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6O8Y.png)
- [Library component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NybW7.png)
- [My project component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORR8p.png)
- [the style that does not work are these classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6GSN.png)

How can I solve it? I followed the instructions on the site, but unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: You can try using the ::ng-deep selector. You can try making a small example of what you're trying to do in stackblitz or include the code in the question.

Comment: PrimeNG is getting unstyled mode soon to allow you to use Tailwind with its components. https://github.com/orgs/primefaces/discussions/200#discussioncomment-7245075
You will need to use custom CSS for the moment with more specific selectors than PrimeNG's if you want to override its styles if you want to do this now.

Comment: I don't understand, i have to use tailwind too? could you be more specific or make an example?

Comment: It is better  to post any codes (for see or test) as code and not as snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you normally can't style sub-components from it's parents due view-encapsulation.

There are a few possibilities:

- use the **global style.css/scss** file. All styles written in this file will be applied to all components in the project.
- use **::ng-deep**.class-name. This will disable the view-encapsulation for this css-rule. It is officially deprecated, but the angular team itself says to use it until there is a better alternative.
- Set **ViewEncapsulation.none** in the @Component decorator, to disable encapsulation for the whole component. keep in mind that css-rules will then apply to the whole project.